# Displaying changes to SCSS on localhost using MAMP

Tags: css, sass, localhost, mamp

I have recently decided to start developing using MAMP on my localhost for a personal project.

However, I am facing an issue where any changes I make to SCSS files do not show when trying to display them on my localhost.

No matter what I do, changes made to the SCSS do not show whatsoever.

After some research I found I needed to convert the files, so I installed an extension to Visual Studio Code called 'Live Sass Compiler' which is a VSCode Extension that helps you to compile/transpile your SASS/SCSS files to CSS files at real-time. It appears to work, but then produces the following error:

```
Change detected - 16/07/2022, 17:08:30
_site-header.scss
--------------------
Compilation Error
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
4 │ @import 'sanitize.css/sanitize';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  c:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\air-light-master\sass\global.scss 4:9  root stylesheet
```

I then added the following to my 'settings.json' for the extension to indicate the stylesheet:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
        "format": "compressed",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/wp-content/themes/air-light-master/css/dev"
    }
]
```

It runs fine now, no errors, and it compiles the CSS to the relevant directory, but none of the changes show still and I'm at a loss on how to get it to work.

Has anybody else experienced this? It is becoming quite frustrating as I cannot view my changes on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

We've actually had the same frustration until realizing that the code actually has to be executed in the production folder. If you change your directory to compile in prod it should work:

```html
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/wp-content/themes/air-light-master/css/prod"
    },
        {
        "format": "compressed",
        "extensionName": ".min.css",
        "savePath": "/wp-content/themes/air-light-master/css/prod"
    }
]
```

We also ran pushed the minified version as that seems to be the one pulled in our local environment, rather that reconfiguring the enqueued scripts.